# Server receiving empty string but client sees correct data

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am encrypting some data client-side with [node-forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge#aes) which I send to the server to be stored on mongoDB collection.

My problem is that, despite being able to generate the data client-side, the server just receives an empty string.

The jQuery code is

```
$('#recordForm').submit(function(event) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this),
    _id = $form.find("input[name='_id']" ).val();
    // Grab form data
    // Crypto
    const params = generateParams();
    const encryptedForm = {
        test: encrypt(params, _id),
    }
    console.log(encryptedForm.test.data); // correctly logs à:û^ìQ%

    const decryptedForm = {
        test: decrypt(params, encryptedForm.test).data,
    }
    console.log("Decrypted text: " + decryptedForm.test);

    url = $form.attr("action");
    // Send the data using post
    $.post(url, {id: encryptedForm.test.data});
});
```

Despite logging `encryptedForm.test.data` correctly, the server just receives back

```
{ id: '' }
```

when logging `req.body`.

I tried using Chrome's developer tools, and logging `encryptedForm.test` which logs this

```
ByteStringBuffer {data: "ÐæáÁþà", read: 0, _constructedStringLength: 8}
    data:""
    read:0
    _constructedStringLength:8
    __proto__: Object
```

which shows the data as `""`. This could explain that the server sees `""` as well but then why would `console.log(encryptedForm.test.data)` correctly log `à:û^ìQ%`?

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:  Adding encrypt() code for clarification

```
// Encrypt under symmetric key
function encrypt(params, m) {
    var cipher = forge.rc2.createEncryptionCipher(params.key);
    cipher.start(params.iv);
    cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(m));
    cipher.finish();
    return cipher.output;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `encrypt().data` is returning a JS object? From the name it would imply that it's returning an encoded string/binary data - hence the issue

Comment: try to use: `$.post(url, { id: encodeURIComponent(encryptedForm.test.data) });`

Comment: `$.post(url, { id: encodeURIComponent(encryptedForm.test.data) });` didn't work either. I think `encrypt()` returns an object from the developer tools you can see the `ByteStringBuffer`.

Comment: try  console.log(encryptedForm.test.data.toHex());

Comment: That returns `Uncaught TypeError: encryptedForm.test.data.toHex is not a function`.

Answer (score 0):

try to post some plain text, that should be posted. There may be something wrong with the characters that you are sending, they are not supported

```
 url = $form.attr("action");
    // Send the data using post
    $.post(url, {id: 'hello'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it after converting everything to hex.

```
function encrypt(params, m) {
    var cipher = forge.rc2.createEncryptionCipher(params.key);
    cipher.start(params.iv);
    cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(m));
    cipher.finish();
    return cipher.output.toHex();
}
```

There is a method in forge to convert the hex to a an object which can be used for decryption. We can do it like so

```
const enc = encrypt(params, m);
// the line below can be used to convert the hex back for decryption
forge.util.createBuffer(forge.util.hexToBytes(enc))
```

This way, everything works in forge for encryption and decryption and the server receives the correct values.